# jquery mobile fieldset width

Tags: jquery-mobile, radio-button, width, fieldset, radio-group

I have a jquerymobile fieldset that looks like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="myid">
```

I want to set a custom width for the fieldset but don't know how to do it.
How can I do this? (preferably without an external plugin)

Thanks

Comment: What is a content of your fieldset, because it is not enough to change a filedset css, content must also be changed.

Comment: I have 3 input radio inside the fieldet

Comment: Take a look at my answer EDIT part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

Here's an example of how to di it with fieldset containing select boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xFPFH/

CSS used is:

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width:100% !important;
}

.ui-select {
    width:33% !important;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Here's an example for radio buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/yUZy8/. When you multiply number of radio button widths it must be equal or greater of **.ui-controlgroup-controls** width.

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.